# C++:Using asynchronous callbacks with generic virtual functions in a base class

Tags: c++, generics, inheritance

Currently I'm writing a C++ program which should contain a somehow very generic base class. Which will have some protected functions

```
class Base{
     virtual void doA() = 0;
     virtual void doB() = 0;
     \\[see below]...
}
```

they will be executed asynchronously and call these as callbacks as soon as they finish:

```
 virtual void doACallback(type1 param1, type2 param2) = 0;
 virtual void doBCallback() = 0;
```

My problem is that the implementation of `doA` and `doB` will be different for every subclass and the callback methods should have the ability to receive different parameters (type and number). Is it possible to manage this while  holding the callback method declaration in the base class? Maybe this can be achieved by going an other way. I'm still new to C++.

Note: Base does not only contain pure virtual functions.

Edit: Because some asked. I want to define the general 'look' of the subclasses. My concret scenario is very complex but let's try an example:

```
class Base{
  virtual void sendData() = 0;
  virtual void sendDataCallback() = 0;
}

class SubclassA:public Base{    
  void sendData() override{
       //send Data by using LibraryA
  }
  void sendDataCallback(ErrorCode aErrorCode) override{
     //handle error Code
  }    
}

class SubclassB:public Base{
  void sendData() override{
       //send Data by using LibraryB
  }
  void sendDataCallback(ErrorCode aErrorCode, Response aResponse) override{
     //handle error Code and handle response
  }    
}
```

It's not the exact scenario, but maybe this clarifies the idea...

Edit 2: If anybody is wondering: In the end I choose to define the callbacks in the subclasses.

Comment: Check "acyclic visitor pattern". Downcasting is required so you may get a runtime exception

Comment: Unclear the interface you want. Can you give an example ?

Comment: I added a example. See my original question.

Comment: How `sendDataCallback` is called? As I understand, it could be last call in `sendData` and so doesn't need to be inside class `Base`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much anything is *possible*.  You could cast to `void*` and back in the derived classes:

```
struct ScrewThis
{
    void addCallback(void * cb) { callbacks.push_back(cb); }
    void executeCallback(int index) const = 0;

    std::vector<void*> callbacks;
};

struct TotalHell : ScrewThis
{
    void executeCallback(int index) const
    {
        auto callback
             = static_cast<std::function<int(int,int)> const*>(callbacks[index]);

        auto i = callback(4,2);
        //...
     }
};
```

But why the hell would you do this?  It's a maintenance nightmare.  Other devs are going to look a it and instantly want to kill themselves...or you....or more likely both.

Are you doing this JUST so that you can share "common" code ('common' in scare quotes because as you can see it is NOT common code).  One huge mistake that was made in the early days of OOP was to think inheritance and such was to increase reuse.  This is wrong.  You increase reuse by composition.

When you end up having to re-implement polymorphism to do what you're trying to do it's time to think maybe what you're trying to do isn't what you should be doing.

Comment: I added a example. See my original question.

Comment: @little_planet - No.  What you want to do doesn't even really make sense.  You seem to be trying to express an is-A relationship when such a relationship doesn't exist.  Like trying to inherit Car from Tree.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using `Command` pattern as your callbacks?
Your derived classes (Derived from Base) should use CommandA and CommandB classes to execute required behaviour.

```
class Command
{
    public:
    virtual void execute() = 0;
};

class CommandA : public Command
{
    public:
    CommandA();
    void execute() override;
};

class CommandB : public Command
{
    public:
    CommandB(int param1, double param2);
    void execute() override;
};
```

And then for concrete class:

```
class Concrete : public Base
{
    public:
    Concrete(Command* callA, Command* callB): callbackA(callA), callbackB(callB)
    {}
    void doA()override
    {
         ...
         callbackA->execute();
    }
    void doB()override
    {
         ...
         callbackB->execute();
    }
    private:
    Command* callbackA;
    Command* callbackB;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. I also don't see the point. The subclasses that implement the callbacks will have to derive from the classes that hold the actual implementations of the do functions anyway, so I don't understand why the classes with the do implementations can't be the ones to declare the callback functions.